# How can I trigger .click() event from an object created using string?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
var r="$(\""+"#table-trip tbody tr a[onclick=\'return FillTripDetails("+$('#<%=hdnPickLocationID.ClientID %>').val()+","+$('#<%= hdnDropLocationID.ClientID %>').val()+","+$('#<%= hdnTripID.ClientID %>').val()+")\']\")";

alert(r);

//$("#table-trip tbody tr a[onclick='return FillTripDetails(3,2,6)']").click();    

r.click();
```

I want to call click event of element that is select in 'r' variable ?

How can i do it ?

Please advise

Comment: `r` us a string... it doesn't have a click method

Comment: so how can i do it can u please advise

Comment: Hello Guys,The solution i got was something like this                                                                    var pl=$('#<%= hdnPickLocationID.ClientID %>').val();
                var dl=$('#<%= hdnDropLocationID.ClientID %>').val();
                var tid=$('#<%= hdnTripID.ClientID %>').val();
                $("#table-trip tbody tr a[onclick=\'return FillTripDetails("+pl+","+dl+","+tid+")\']").click();

Answer (score 1):

r is a string variable. To trigger the click, you would need selectors for selecting the dom and then jquery methods to trigger their events like click. Something like this:

```
$("#table-trip tbody tr a").click();
```

or

```
$("#table-trip tbody tr a").trigger('click');
```